# Extjs 4.1 - How to get embed data inside store that sent from server

Tags: extjs, grid, store, extjs4.1

I have a grid panel and i want to get data that i embed in store

My json look like (`embed` is my embed data)

```
({"total":"20","results":[{...}], "embed": [{...}] })
```

How to get `embed` data in my `load` function. Thanks

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'MyDataObject',
     autoLoad: true,
     pageSize:10,
     proxy: {
          type: 'ajax',
          url: 'data.php',
          reader: {
              type: 'json',
              totalProperty: 'total', // total data
              root: 'results'                       
          }
    }
    ,listeners: {
          load: function( store, records, successful, eOpts ){
               if (successful) {
                    alert(store.embed) // ?? how to get it      
               }
          }
    }
});
```

Comment: "store.data.embed" will give you an object with embed data

Comment: @Daemon don't work that undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proxy keeps a reference to the `rawData` property for the most recent load.

`console.log(store.getProxy().getReader().rawData.embed);`